# Redirect the non-www URL to the www URL

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, hosting

I have referred all the related questions and tried the answer given, but it's not working for my site.

In my `.htaccess` file, I have written below code to redirect non-www to www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Are there any settings in Joomla that need to be set so it will use the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Yes Shakti, it is enabled and I have check this by using below code:

Comment: RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Redirect /google.html http://www.google.com

Comment: when I use http://example.com, it shows Google Error-404 Not found                                                                   Will there be any hosting issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I use -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The differences are minor but should make it work. This works completely outside the scope of Joomla, you shouldn't have to do anything to Joomla for this to work.

Comment: Does it give you an error? This code definitely works on Joomla installs, I have it on 40+ sites.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the following into your `.htaccess` to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: what's the purpose of 'nd' ?

Comment: @BryanH, very kind of you to edit the edited, at least could you check if the "nd" is correct or not? As much as I look, I can't find anything about it.

Comment: @YannisDran it looks like it was a typo. According to the [RewriteRule docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), flags have to go in the brackets, and there is no 'nd' flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this works for me all the time

Comment: could you please describe your solution better?